# rspec test not working in Chapter 7 of Hartl's Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm in section 7.1.3 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I can't get FactoryGirl to work correctly in testing. It doesn't appear to be a problem with FactoryGirl because I also tried creating a User with User.create in a before hook and had the same problem.  Here are the results I'm getting:

[image: console]

I took a screenshot of the error in the browser when the test was running: (Couldn't find a way to look at results in console.  They did not show when I ran the test console.)

[image: Rails Error in Browser]

I have restarted the server and console.  And have done a migrate on the Test Environment to make sure its up to date.

Below are my files.  You can also find this on github at https://github.com/cjaypierson/sample_app/tree/sign-up

spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "User Pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Profile page" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { visit user_path(user) }

        it { should have_content(user.name) }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
    end

  describe "signup page" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        it { should have_content('Sign up') }
        it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
    end
end
```

spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        name "Ed Sullivan"
        email "ed@example.com"
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"
    end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb')
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'support/utilities.rb'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

models/user.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0_5

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'pg'

gem 'heroku_secrets', github: 'alexpeattie/heroku_secrets'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140708142214) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  encoding: unicode
  database: sadevelopment

test:
  <<: *default
  encoding: unicode
  database: satest
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I went past chapter 7.1.3 a while ago, so I looked it up for you.

In the book:

```
describe "Profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
end
```

Your code:

```
describe "Profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(@user) }

    it { should have_content(@user.name) }
    it { should have_title(@user.name) }
end
```

Try removing the '@' in the `@user` variable, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I still get the same error though.  I forgot to change that back after trying to test the code without using FactoryGirl. I updated the code in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Hartl's tutorial is currently using RSpec 2.13.1. RSpec 3 has many breaking changes, as mentioned here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/upgrade

If you're learning, when going through his tutorial I highly recommend that you use the same gem versions that he does:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```